# Partitioning and changing boot disk

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning

My PC has two disks - a 120Gb SSD (C: drive) and a 1Tb HDD (D: drive). I was a bit naive when I bought the SSD, thinking it would be plenty for "just" the OS (Win 10). Other stuff inevitably ends up on there and I've now run out of space on C:.

I don't want to spend money on a replacement SSD, so was wondering if I could create a new partition on the HDD and image the C: drive onto that. The aim is to have a new bootable C: drive (say 500gb), and what's left of the existing D: drive and its files on the remaining 500gb. (Eventually I'd also want to plug the SSD back in, reformat, and use it as a backup drive). I'm happy to take the performance hit of going back to a HDD and having to wait longer for Windows to boot.

I'm looking for help/pointers on how to go about this, assuming it's possible. Presumably I would need a tool like Macrium Reflect, but I don't know what imaging settings to use, and how to ensure that the PC will boot from the new C: drive - whether that's done in Macrium, the BIOS or elsewhere. I don't want to end up with a brick!

Comment: First up, I guess I should have been using the term "clone" rather than "image". Second, this doesn't appear to be possible - cloning to another disk would overwrite existing partitions (or at least require them to be deleted first), which I wanted to avoid. Looks like a new disk then...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/) for disk formatting and partitioning. I recommend that you backup your important files first before wiping the disk.

Install your Windows 10 OS on your 1 TB HDD.
After Windows 10 installation you can then create a partition allocating 500 GB for your Windows 10 OS and 500 GB for your files.

Comment: I wanted to avoid wiping the HDD and just create a second partition on it, making this the bootable/OS. Is that not possible?

Comment: Found something, I'd thought this would be helpful [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/214477/how-to-dual-boot-two-or-more-versions-of-windows)